# Boot partition where is WIndows installed before Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

Recently I have installed Ubuntu on my another hard disk drive which is separated from the Windows7 System. I have 2 hard drives (One running windows, secondary is separated on two partitions). Because I have created new partition, I decided to install Ubuntu on it. After successful installation, I cannot boot the hard drive which runs Windows7. Can anybody help? I have tried to start it through BIOS but I cannot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two hard disks in my desktop machine, booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu respectively. I think I made sure to install Windows first, then Ubuntu second. I'm using EFI boot, though. Are you using legacy BIOS or EFI/UEFI?

Comment: I installed windows first, I think it's UEFI

Comment: Have you got the two drives selected as EFI boot drives in your firmware setup (or BIOS, to be old fashioned)?

Comment: I have changed Bios ROM from Legacy to EFI, thank you!